# Indesign SDK Panels TextEditbox

Tags: sdk, adobe-indesign

how to get the TextEditbox value for indesign panel. I have tried the following code:

```
GetTextControlData(kDYNTextEditBoxWidgetID);
```

It returns an error like as below:

```
error C3861: 'GetTextControlData': identifier not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `GetTextControlData`() is available with `IDialogController`. Are you including `IDialogController.h` header in the file ?
Another approach could be to use `IWidgetUtils::QueryRelatedWidget()` to get `ITextControlData` for this widget. From `ITextControlData`, you can `GetString()`